# Read text file between specific lines of text in c++

Tags: c++, string, search, getline

I am currently working on parsing a file into program memory.

The file to parse looks like this:

```
    file info
    second line of file info
    date

    # col1    col2    col3    col4   col5      col6      col7    col8     col9   col10    col11     col12     col13     col14  
    firstSetOfElements
    4
           2       1       1       0       3       1       2       3       0 -49.4377        0 0       -26.9356 -24.5221
           3       2       1       0       3       2       4       3       13.7527 -43.2619       0 0       -19.3462 -28.0525
           4       3       1       0       3       4       1       3       14.2459 43.5163       0 0       33.3506 15.2988
           5       4       1       0       3       2       1       4       49.4377 0       0 0       25.0818 38.3082


    # col1      col2      col3      col4      col5      col6
    secondSetOfElements
    1
         1 4 3 4 1 2
```

What I am trying to do:

```
    file.open(FILENAME, ios::in); // Open file
    if (file.is_open()) 
    { 
            // Get the line number where "firstSetOfElements" is located. Store the line number.
            // Go to the line after that line, and store the integer listed there as a variable (`int noFirstElems`).
            // (this is the number of rows I will be parsing into the first array).
    // start parsing at the first line of the array (the line under the previous)     
         while (getline(file, firstLineOfFirstSetToParse)) //starting at the first row of data array elements, begin parsing into text file (this I've got handled).
         {
                 //add a row vector until you get to a blank line (which will be after 4 rows of data).
         }
```

After doing this for the "firstSetOfElements" array, I will then do the same thing to parse the "secondSetOfElements" data into an array, as above.

I have parsed the data just fine, but have not found a resource I can understand for setting begin/end points for the lines I am to parse.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that an empty line is the end of your set. Or also a line not beginning with a space/tab is the end of the set.

Comment: Unfortunately, computers aren't very good at reading between the lines.  (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string trimmed(string& input)
{
    size_t firstNonWSIdx = input.find_first_not_of(" ");
    size_t lastNonWSIdx = input.find_last_not_of(" ");
    firstNonWSIdx = (firstNonWSIdx == string::npos ? 0 : firstNonWSIdx);
    return input.substr(firstNonWSIdx, lastNonWSIdx);
}

void resetStrStream(istringstream& sstr, string const& newInput)
{
    sstr.clear();
    sstr.str(newInput);
}

void readFile(char const* fileName, vector<vector<float> >& data)
{
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string input;
    istringstream iss;
    while(infile)
    {
        getline(infile, input);
        string token = trimmed(input);
        if (token.compare("setOfElements") == 0)
        {
            getline(infile, input);
            resetStrStream(iss, trimmed(input));
            int arraySize;
            iss >> arraySize;
            vector<float> values;
            int i = 0;
            while(i++ < arraySize)
            {
                getline(infile, input);
                resetStrStream(iss, trimmed(input));
                float val;
                while (iss >> val)
                {
                   values.push_back(val);
                } 
            }
            data.push_back(values);
        }
    }    
}

void testData(vector<vector<float> >& data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << data[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector< vector<float> > data;
    readFile("textfile.txt", data);
    testData(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very good. I haven't written my final code yet, but I will respond to this soon. Thanks very much. (No code was really even necessary...just hints at things to think about would have been good too!)

Comment: why do you trim "input" from getline? isn't extraneous whitespace already trimmed, or have I misunderstood the function?

Comment: The whitespaces aren't automatically removed and since I was doing a string compare to identify the beginning of each set, I had to trim the string. You might not have to trim the string representation of lines that contain your set elements since string stream by default uses space as the delimiter (to my surprise, it extracted set elements correctly even when it encountered multiple spaces between elements!).

Comment: Yeah that was what I found too (which was a fantastic suprise as my data is separated by varying lengths of whitespace). My code looks a lot like yours but I've still got a weird array population or printing issue to work out. I don't clear the stringstream, however. Maybe that's it. Thanks so much--your code helped so much (and many thanks for breaking up into functions/showing the passing of pointers.)

Comment: did you ever run this exact code? I feel like the vector "values" isn't declared in the right spot...shouldn't it be in the `while(i++ < arraySize)` loop? otherwise you end up just pushing back every `val` in the whole block of data to it (unless you added a line to clear it after each `data` push back.

Comment: Yes, I did run the code and verify that it read a sample file correctly. The vector "values" is re-defined for every new set, the while loop is to read each line in a set. My understanding was you wanted your set to be an array of floats and your entire data-set be an array of array of floats.

Answer (score 1):

The problem based on the way you have described is straightforward to solve: read line by line, scan for a token named "SetOfElements" and treat the next line as the size of your 2D-array, and then read `size` number of lines and store them into your array.

But, your file's layout is confusing: your comment line (starting with #) says there are going to be 8 columns, but subsequent lines contain 14 columns. Is your program supposed to ignore the last 6 columns? Also, your elements seem to be mixture of ints and floats, unless the columns 1 through 8 are also floats that don't have a fractional part.

If in fact, the data-type is mixed, and columns 1-8 have to read as ints and the remaining as floats, then your parser code is going to be complex otherwise, it should be simple `getline... scan line... continue` kind of algorithm.

Also, do your set delimiters change? The first set is identified by "firstSetOfElements" and the second set's id is "secondSetOfElements", it would be easier if they simply "SetOfElements", otherwise you would have construct the delimiter string before reading every new set of elements.

Comment: My apologies! I simply forgot to list all 14 columns. The "#" is text within the file, not a comment about the file. I didn't make the file, I am just making a parser. The set delimiters will change, which is why I made them different. I am editing my question to make things more clear.

Comment: I will be tackling the issue of mixed data types later. For now, I just need to commit them to program memory.

Comment: Okay, so 14 columns then. Is the data-type mixed? do the data-types appear in order: first 8 columns int and the next 6 are float? If so we need more complicated logic to create the arrays, for instance for your your first set would be a 4 x 8 array of ints and 4 x 6 array of float. If they don't appear in order and if a row is interspersed with floats and ints, the logic would get even more cumbersome.

Comment: Oh! okay, then lets assume you would read them as floats, that simplifies things for now. Final piece: does your set delimiters/identifiers have to be "firstSetOfElements", "secondSetOfElements", etc? Can they not be "setOfElements"? That will simplify the logic even more, we can then scan just for "setOfElements" and read everything below that line and the next occurrence of "setOfElements" into the array.

Comment: Thanks so much DigitalEye, but the parser itself isn't what I need help with. That was the easy part (found better resources I suppose). I thought I made that clear down below, but I guess I should have added that to the code example. All I really need help with is how to get line numbers of specific strings and start the parsing BETWEEN those lines. Maybe I need to scrap this and rewrite it. My apologies again.

Comment: @Rachel: I don't understand why you want to keep track of line numbers, below is a solution that doesn't involve line numbers and to simplify things, I called the set delimiter "setOfElements". The below code reads data into a `vector<vector<float> >` without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you a few ideas:

```
std::string line;
int line_num = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
     assert(getline(input, line))); // ignore 3 lines

while (input >> set_name)
{
    if (set_name == '#') { input.ignore('\n'); continue; }
    std::vector<std::vector<float>>>& set = sets[set_name];
    if (input >> rows)
        for (int i = 0; i < rows && getline(input, line); ++i)
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            set.push_back(std::vector<float>());
            while (iss >> num) set.back().push_back(num);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony D, got the vector building part--that's not the prob (mentioned in question). My issue is that I have multiple element sets to parse into vector arrays in the file, so I must *scan* the file for the label elements, use the line below to find out how many elements will be in the array (gives us the number of rows) and then  after the blank line, parse the data block into the array. Do this for each set of elements in the file.

Comment: @Rachael... yes... what do you think the `input >> set_name` and `input >> rows` is doing? ;-] Did you notice there's a `map` keyed on set names, with each element being a vector of vectors?

Comment: @Rachel: My final comment on this thread :) You don't need to keep track of line numbers, you just need to scan for the token that marks the beginning of your set, then do another getline() for the number of rows to scan, then do row count number of getline()s to read in your array. Like I mentioned, the code, I posted reads your data correctly.

Comment: @TonyD This is great--writing up my final code this evening. Yours was definitely the most concise. Thank you.